# Query running in PostgreSQL and Talend query builder but generating error wile running the job

Tags: postgresql, talend

I am converting a view into a talend job. The query is running fine in postgresql and Talend sql builder but when I am running jobs, its generating error messages. Column not found etc.

Please help

Comment: You are giving too much information in your question, so anwering it is too easy to us. This is the reason why nobody want's to help.

Answer (score 0):

Could I ask which Talend version you are using? Also, which components have you included in your job? I understand you have a column not found error message and it would be interesting to know which message exactly you are getting on your end so we can determine where the error is coming from.

A reason why you could be getting the "column not found" error is because your table names and columns names are in mixed case. Therefore if it's the case names have to be set in quotes, otherwise the database sets it to uppercase and will throw error table/column not found.

Comment: It's been years since I asked this question and I forgot about it. However to add closure regarding this issue in case it helps someone in future -

This issue was caused by extremely long field names as selected by our client. While the query runs fine even in the SQL builder of Talend, once the job is run, those column names get split up and sent to next line with an extra space causing the query to fail. 

Trimming the column names shorter solved the problems.